# WCF Service - what happens when client doesn't get the response?

Tags: wcf, web-services

We have developed a WCF service which acts as an API to our system.

some of the methods expose functionality which eventually writes and updates data to DB.

Lets say that the client sent one of those requests, the service performed the needed operations while the client disconnects for some reason and did not get the response.

An example of problematic data being updated - "Add X to Member M".

just to make things clearer - client sends a request and receives a response which notifies about success/failure of the request.

**our problem is** - what if the client sends a request which is performed but the response is not received - how can we notify the client about the reponse?

Comment: An exception is generated if the client doesn't receive a response from the service. Isn't that helpful enough?

Comment: I'm talking about the service side... what should I do if the client gets an error message but the service has performed the operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't necessarily do anything. The service has performed what the client asked. If the client notices that it was disconnected, then it should ask the service if the action was performed, using a separate call.

If you absolutely require reliable messaging, then look into the reliable messaging options in WCF.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use an asynchronous  messaging pattern, so instead of submitting a request and waiting on a response, you would submit a request and continue on, and have either a callback contract or an external-facing service contract that your service can connect back to (a callback contract is the best option when you're dealing with a typical client-server scenario). The downside to callbacks is that they're only supported using two-way bindings (WSDualHttpBinding, NetTcpBinding, etc.), which will limit interoperability with non-WCF technologies.

Another option would be to use an enterprise service bus. That's basically software that sits in the middle and coordinates everything between your client and service. That way if your client times out, the enterprise service bus can trigger a "compensation" activity that ensures both your client and service end up in a consistent state.

**Update:**
Enterprise Service Bus is a very broad topic. [Wikipedia is a good place to start](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus), and [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=enterprise+service+bus&x=0&y=0) [offers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596006756) [several](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430210575) [books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1743047991) [covering](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321200683) [various](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847198287) [platforms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988215) [in detail](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847194400). As far as actual implementations, Microsoft offers BizTalk Server, IBM has WebSphere ESB, Oracle bought BEA Systems which offered AquaLogic (now Oracle Service Bus), and there are multiple open source systems as well including Apache ServiceMix, Apache Synapse, and Mule.

Comment: thanks joel, about the first option, we dropped it because of the downsides you described. about the second option - can you direct me to some helpful info about this? I haven't heard of it before...

Comment: @Mithir I've updated my answer (I couldn't fit all the links in a comment)